# How to install Jena SemanticWeb Framework in Play Framework

Tags: semantics, playframework, jena

I put jena jar files in the lib folder and see the message:

```
A JPA error occurred (Cannot start a JPA manager without a 
properly configured database): No datasource configured
```

what am I doing wrong?

I found the answer. This was a problem in Play.
There's some reason put in front of the class directive from the module javax 
I do not know why it happened, simply remove and earned

Answer (score 1):

This error doesn't asoociate with jena, because if your dont't choose model (dataset) while your execute query, you will get next message - `No dataset description for query` and `com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecException`. But if you choose jena as datasource in play, you may get your message(sorry, but i don't know much about Play).

What operations you do with jena?

Comment: I know play much better than jena so if I can help, don't hesitate to ask! Several brains sometimes give a better solution :)

Comment: I found the answer. This was a problem in Play.
There's some reason put in front of the class directive from the module javax
I do not know why it happened, simply remove and earned

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "some reason put in front of the class directive" but if you solved your pb, it's great ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much Jena but it seems that some persistent ontologies might be stored into database. Thus, it would mean Jena needs a database connection?
Is this error an error of Jena and not from Play?
What do you try to do in your code before getting this error?
If Jena requires some configuration and resource creation before using it, you should think of creating a little Jena play plugin to initialize your Jena context...